# Access level to Database::$db must be public

Tags: php, class, access-levels

I am getting the following error:

> PHP Fatal error:  Access level to Database::$db must be public (as in class phpLive) in C:\Users\ryannaddy\Documents\NetBeansProjects\phpLive\plugins\Database\Database.plugin.php on line 92
>
> Fatal error: Access level to Database::$db must be public (as in class phpLive) in C:\Users\ryannaddy\Documents\NetBeansProjects\phpLive\plugins\Database\Database.plugin.php on line 92

Part of class `phpLive.php`. This is how my Database::$db property gets created. As you can see it is a dynamically created property. I then use `__get()` to access the property like in my next block of code.

```php
<?php
class phpLive{
    public function loadPlugin($class, $info){
        $this->functionName = __FUNCTION__;
        $info               = (object)$info;
        $file               = $this->location . "/plugins/" . $info->root . "/" . $info->fileName;
        if(is_file($file)){
            require_once $file;
            $instance                   = (string)$info->instanceName;
            $info                       = (isset($info->information)) ? $info->information : "";
            $reflection = new ReflectionClass($class);
            $this->$instance = $reflection->newInstanceArgs(array($info));
            $this->extension[$instance] = $this->$instance;
            return $this->$instance;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public function __get($name){
        switch($name){
            default:
                if(array_key_exists($name, $this->extension)){
                    $ret = $this->extension[$name];
                }else{
                    $ret = false;
                }
                break;
        }
        return $ret;
    }
}
```

Note: `$class` and `$info` are loaded from a config file that looks like this:

```
$plugins = array(
    "Database" => array(
        "root"         => "Database",
        "fileName"     => "Database.plugin.php",
        "instanceName" => "db",
        "sessionRef"   => "db",
        "information"  => array(
            "dbtype"   => "mysql",
            "hostname" => "localhost",
            "database" => "test",
            "username" => "root",
            "password" => "xxx",
        )
    ),
);
```

This is how I use the property `db`

```
<?php

require_once '../../phpLive.php';

$live->db->select("select * from users where fname in(?,?)", array("Billy", "Bob"))->each(function($col, $name){
    echo "here";
});
```

So, the method `select` is in class/file `Database.plugin.php` which extends `phpLive`

```
class Database extends phpLive{
    public function select(){
        $info = $this->queryinfo(func_get_args());
        $this->query($info->query, $info->args);
        return $this;
    }
}
```

The select works fine, but as soon as I add the each method (found in the `phpLive` class) I get the above error. What can I do to make this work?

Comment: What is in C:\Users\ryannaddy\Documents\NetBeansProjects\phpLive\plugins\Database\Database.plugin.php on line 92?

Comment: @Gordon This is on that line: `}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There must be a private variable named $db in file Database.‌​plugin.php or its children class.

Comment: Can you paste all content of the Database.‌​plugin.php file here.

Comment: You were correct! `private $db = null` in file `Database.plugin.php` It got rid of the error, but THere is now a new unrelated error with PDO that I need to figure out!

Comment: Fixed all the errors now `echo "here";` displays twice since there were two results returned from the query! Thanks for the help!